# Map function returns value inside Iterable List ? Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, hashmap

I have a question in regards Scala map function.
Why does the map function return the result wrapped in a List collection?
Example

```
val exMap = Map("k" -> Map("kate" -> 34))
 exMap.map{
   case (k,v) => println(v.map(_._2))
   }
```

Why this gives as a `output : List(34)`
instead of 34 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val exMap = Map("k" -> Map("kate" -> 34),"a" -> Map("abe" -> 31))
    exMap.map{
      case ( k :String,v : Map[String,Int]) => println(
        v //  Map("kate" -> 34) , Map("abe" -> 31)
          .map(
            _._2 // 34, 31
          )
        .foreach(println(_)) //place to retrieve each element and perform action over it
      )
    } // by default map will collect all the returning value to a single list
```

Comment: inside the second map  if we print the values we get List(34) instead of 34

Comment: please use foreach which I have now updated in the ans

Answer (score 2):

Here v represents the internal

```
Map("kate" -> 34)
```

which could contain as many values, example

```
Map("kate" -> 34, "sam" -> 43)
```

and in above code snippet with variable "v" we are representing values of this interval map which comes out to be List(34, 43)

Here in your example map contains only single key-value pair but can have as many key value pairs hence return of fetching all values is List(values)

Comment: What should I do in order to retrieve each element over iteration instead of a List of elements ? I can seem to get the intuition behind it